# Authenticating azcopy or az storage cli to upload to Azurite docker emulator

Tags: azcopy, azurite

I started an Azurite docker on local VM and then tried to copy data to it by azcopy and az CLI  like below

```
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCOUNT="devstoreaccount1"
export AZURE_STORAGE_ACCESS_KEY="Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw=="
azcopy copy /local/data/ http://localvm:10000/devstoreaccount1/data/test --from-to LocalBlob
INFO: Scanning...

failed to perform copy command due to error: Login Credentials missing. No SAS token or OAuth token is present and the resource is not public
```

I want to authenticate with the Account key and Account name and preferably be able to copy using azcopy.
I scoured the GitHub and stack to find only one https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/867 issue and there is nothing there regarding auth. It looks like I am missing something that's obvious. Your help will be much appreciated.

The version used were:
azure-cli 2.11.1
azcopy version 10.7.0

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I was able to getaway with using az cli instead of azcopy.

```
export AZURE_STORAGE_CONNECTION_STRING="DefaultEndpointsProtocol=http;AccountName=devstoreaccount1;AccountKey=Eby8vdM02xNOcqFlqUwJPLlmEtlCDXJ1OUzFT50uSRZ6IFsuFq2UVErCz4I6tq/K1SZFPTOtr/KBHBeksoGMGw==;BlobEndpoint=http://azuritedockerhost:10000/devstoreaccount1;"
az storage blob upload -f local-file -c container-name -n dir/blob-name
```

Hope this helps someone. Plus it would really nice to be able to use azcopy too so if anybody finds out how it will greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

The Microsoft documentation '[Get started with AzCopy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json)' indicates the following under the 'Run AzCopy' heading:

> As an owner of your Azure Storage account, you aren't automatically
> assigned permissions to access data. Before you can do anything
> meaningful with AzCopy, you need to decide how you'll provide
> authorization credentials to the storage service.

Under the next heading 'Authorize AzCopy', the documentation states:

> You can provide authorization credentials by using Azure Active Directory
> (AD), or by using a Shared Access Signature (SAS) token.

Even though you're accessing a local storage emulator (Azurite) on your local machine, the AzCopy app wants an OAuth token or SAS token. See this [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/translator/document-translation/create-sas-tokens?tabs=Containers) to generate SAS tokens for local storage or online storage.

A [SAS token](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-v10?toc=/azure/storage/blobs/toc.json#option-2-use-a-sas-token) must be appended to the destination parameter in the `azcopy copy` command. I use the Active AD (OAuth token) authorization credentials option so that I can run multiple `azcopy` commands without appending a SAS token to every command.

To resolve the AzCopy error you're getting `"Failed to perform copy command due to error: Login Credentials missing. No SAS token or OAuth token is present and the resource is not public"`, enter the following into a command prompt or Windows PowerShell:

`azcopy login --tenant-id=<your-tenant-directory-id-from-azure-portal>`

and then follow the steps this command returns. Here's a [reference](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-authorize-azure-active-directory#authorize-a-user-identity) to `azcopy login`. From the heading '[Authorize without a secret store](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-authorize-azure-active-directory#authorize-without-a-secret-store)' in this reference: "

> The azcopy login command retrieves an OAuth token and then places that
> token into a secret store on your system.

From '[Authorize a user identitiy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/storage/common/storage-use-azcopy-authorize-azure-active-directory#authorize-a-user-identity)' heading:

> After you've successfully signed in, you can close the browser window
> and begin using AzCopy.

Use `azcopy logout` from a command prompt to stop any more AzCopy commands.

Here are the steps with screen captures for the login process as well as where to find a tenant ID to get the AzCopy login process going.

1. Get tenant ID from the Azure portal.

[image]

2. In a command prompt enter the `azcopy login` command along with the `--tenant-id` parameter.

[image]

3. Follow the steps indicated in the command prompt: "...use a web browser to open the page https://microsoft.com/devicelogin and enter the code...".

[image]

4. "A sign-in window will appear. In that window, sign into your Azure account by using your Azure account credentials."

[image]

5. "After you've successfully signed in, you can close the browser window and begin using AzCopy."

[image]

You can run your original `azcopy copy /local/data/ http://localvm:10000/devstoreaccount1/data/test --from-to LocalBlob` without the need for the `export` entries in your question.

Answer (score 0):

AzCopy deliberately avoids support for account key authentication, because an account key has full admin privileges: https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-azcopy/issues/186

The only workaround I have found so far is to generate a SAS (for the *container*) in Azure Storage Explorer, and then use the SAS URL with AzCopy.